# wicd system tray indicator on 16.04

Tags: unity, indicator, system-tray, wicd

the wicd system tray indicator question has been asked over and over again, but none of the solutions worked on 16.04.

on 14.04 it appears to be fixed with [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/on-demand-system-tray-for-ubuntu.html)
but it still doesn't show on 16.04 even though it works for other applications.

And i get this error when starting: wicd-client

```
AttributeError: 'IndicatorTrayIconGUI' object has no attribute 'set_from_name'
```

Is there any way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: install python-appindicator

```
sudo apt-get install python-appindicator
```

and then reboot.

Additionally, install python3-notify2 for network notifications

```
sudo apt-get install python3-notify2
```

Source

[How to re-enable the systray (indicator panel) after latest updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612912/how-to-re-enable-the-systray-indicator-panel-after-latest-updates)

Comment: Are you sure this addresses the question which is specifically about WICD?

Comment: Yes. WIDC is a python application, becase it require python-appindicator on ubuntu. Fhurder, this solution work on my ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I can confirm that this works in Ubuntu 18.04 with Unity Desktop.