# Replace default network manager

Tags: network-manager

I'm trying to replace the default network manager with wicd. Wicd installs fine, but there is no notification icon, and the default network manager is not disabled. If I log off my wifi using the default network manager and log on using wicd, I cannot access the internet.

Using ps -e I can see that both Network Manager and Wicd is running - should they both be running?

Wicd is set to start at boot, but I don't see it, when the computerstarts. Do I need to do something else than just install Wicd to replace the default manager? Should I apt-get remove the default manager? I have really skow wifi, and after to computer sleeps, I loose the connection completely.

So what Im looking for is a complete replacement of Network Manager to make my connection a lot more stable.

The possible duplicate suggested by Huckle applies to older versions of Ubuntu.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This method does not seem to work for Ubuntu 14.04 and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

OK -so I found a way, although it seems more like a workaround than an actual solution:
I used GGleb's answer in this thread to enable system tray icons: [How to re-enable the systray (indicator panel) after latest updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/612912/how-to-re-enable-the-systray-indicator-panel-after-latest-updates).
His solution is to install the **Indicator Systemtray Unity**. His instructions was:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fixnix/indicator-systemtray-unity
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-systemtray-unity
```

This enabled the wicd icon in the system tray. I still had the default Network Manager showing up and giving me notifications. I used Synaptic to completely remove everything connected to Network Manager and rebooted. Now I only have wicd's icon.

It even seems that my wifi connection is more stable than before.